# Confusion with $F=-\nabla V$, $F$ conservative

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy, conventions

I am rather confused by the relationship $F=-\nabla V$.

If a pen drops from a height it loses potential energy so $\nabla V$ is negative. From the above equation this means that the gravitational force acting on the pen is positive, but isn't it  acting in the negative direction (downwards)?

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is in how you understand the gradient. Define your z-axis. Lets say it points up. Now $$V(z) = mgz$$. Thus gradient of V(z), that is $$\nabla V(z) = mg \hat z$$. Here, $$\hat z$$ is an unit vector pointing up. So the force will be a vector of length mg, pointing down, because of the minus sign.

Comment: But the pen is dropping so the potential is decreasing?

Comment: You are somehow confusing the temporal movement of the pen to the definition of gradient. Sure, the pen is moving to -z direction. That is because of te potential is decreasing to direction -z. Thus it is increasing to direction z. Gradient of the potential thus points to +z direction. Gradient always points to direction of steepest rise. That is why one has the minus sign, because we want to go downhill.

Comment: Yes, when the pen falls from a high location to a low location, its gravitational potential energy decreases. What alternative were you thinking of?

Comment: And that is because the gravitational potential is lower at the lower location.

Answer (score 1):

I think what is missing is the definitions of $F$ and $V$.

Consider first the definition of potential energy.
The potential energy at a point relative to another point is the work done by a external force (eg the force exerted by you on the mass, $\vec F_{my}$) in taking the mass from the first point to the second point.

That force which you exert on the mass in doing the work is equal and opposite to the force due to the gravitational field (let it be produced by the Earth) on the mass, $ F_{mE}$ as there is no change in kinetic energy of the mass.

So $\Delta V =  F_{my} \cdot \Delta  r = -  F_{mE} \cdot \Delta  r \Rightarrow \frac{\Delta V}{\Delta r} = \nabla V = - F_{mE}$

So this equation is telling you that as you lift a mass by applying an upward force on the mass and the potential energy of the mass increases the force due to the gravitation attraction of the Earth is downwards.