# Why the force acting on a particle is the negative gradient of a scalar potential?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, potential-energy, conventions

For conservative forces we can proof that it is a gradient of a scalar potential, but why we use the negative sign? In every book I searched, it said that it is like an agreement between physicists, but the books didn't explain the reasons of this agreement.

Comment: Duplicate question? Confusion with F=−∇V  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/231434/

Comment: FYI: [wikipedia: Potential energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy#Work_and_potential_energy)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is mainly in order to be able to write the total energy of the system as

$$
E=T+V
$$
where $T$ is the kinetic energy of the system. It is far more useful to choose the signs of the terms in the total energy to be $+1$ once and for all, rather than setting the force equal to plus the gradient of the potential.

The link between the conventions is as follows. Suppose you have a classical particle in one dimension, subject to a spatially varying potential. Then

$$
E=\frac{mv^{2}}{2}+V(x)
$$
Differentiating both members with respect to the time, you get

$$
\frac{dE}{dt}=mv\frac{dv}{dt}+\frac{dV}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=v\left(ma+\frac{dV}{dx}\right)
$$
As the total energy of the system is conserved in the case of interest, the energy doesn't change in time and the left member is zero: $dE/dt=0$. As in general $v\neq0$, if you use the plus convention for the energy, you get
$$
ma=-\frac{dV}{dx}
$$
where $ma=F$, the force on the particle, so you must use the minus convention for the potential. The argument generalizes not only to systems composed of many particles in more than one dimensions, but also to systems made up of fields and all kind of different objects (gravity in general relativity, strings in string theory, etc.). The argument that sets the convention in the general case (i.e. that clarifies the relation between the convention in the equation of motions and that in the energy) is written in the formalism of Lagrangian dynamics, and follows from something called an "Action Principle".